# One div input element will not pull information from sessionStorage using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VddPH.png)I am trying to develop a ticketing tool for work and its a template site to make taking notes for helpdesk more easily and when something is an escalation and you click the button for escalation template. When the escalation template loads I want it to pull information from session storage to avoid copying and pasting notes already taken.

This is how I am storing the information in session storage and I checked via Chrome browser that information is being stored in the session storage.

```
if(callInbound)
{
        sessionStorage.setItem("ACTIVITYTYPE", document.form1.activity.value);
        sessionStorage.setItem("CONTACTNAME", document.form1.name.value);
        sessionStorage.setItem("VIPSTATUS", document.form1.vip.value);
        sessionStorage.setItem("CONTACTNUMBER", document.form1.phone.value);
        sessionStorage.setItem("CALLERLOCATION", document.form1.location.value);
        sessionStorage.setItem("ISSUEDESCRIPTION",document.form1.issueDescription.value); <--PROBLEM ITEM
        sessionStorage.setItem("ERRORMESSAGE", document.form1.errorMessage.value);
        sessionStorage.setItem("TROUBLESHOOTING", document.form1.troubleshooting.value);
        sessionStorage.setItem("KNOWLEDGEUSED", document.form1.knowledgeUsed.value);
        sessionStorage.setItem("SEARCHTERMSTRIED", document.form1.searchtermsTried.value);
        sessionStorage.setItem("SCREENSHOTSATTACHED", document.form1.screenshotsAttached.value);
        sessionStorage.setItem("SURVEYOFFERED", document.form1.surveyOffered.value);
        sessionStorage.setItem("SURVEYTAKEN", document.form1.surveyTaken.value);
}
```

This is the page where the information is being loaded and all but the one identified as problem is being populated into the template.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"><title>DSI Call Outbound</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DSI.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
  let callInboundCallDropped = sessionStorage.getItem("CALLINBOUNDCALLDROPPED");
  let callOutboundCallDropped = sessionStorage.getItem("CALLOUTBOUNDCALLDROPPED")
  let additionalIssue = sessionStorage.getItem("ADDITIONALISSUE");
  let voicemailCallBack = sessionStorage.getItem("VOICEMAILRECEIVED");

  if (callInboundCallDropped == "true")
  {
    document.form1.issueDescription.value = sessionStorage.getItem("ISSUEDESCRIPTION");<--Problem Item
    document.form1.name.value = sessionStorage.getItem("CONTACTNAME");
    document.form1.phone.value = sessionStorage.getItem("CONTACTNUMBER");
    document.form1.errorMessage.value = sessionStorage.getItem("ERRORMESSAGE");  
    
  }
  else if (callOutboundCallDropped == "true")
  {
    document.form1.name.value = sessionStorage.getItem("CONTACTNAME");
    document.form1.phone.value = sessionStorage.getItem("CONTACTNUMBER");
    document.form1.issueDescription.value = sessionStorage.getItem("ISSUEDESCRIPTION");<--Problem item
    document.form1.errorMessage.value = sessionStorage.getItem("ERRORSMESSAGE");
    
  }
  else if(additionalIssue == "true")
  {
    document.form1.activity.value = "***ADDITIONAL ISSUE***";
    document.form1.name.value = sessionStorage.getItem("CONTACTNAME");
    document.form1.phone.value = sessionStorage.getItem("CONTACTNUMBER");
    
    
  }
  else if(voicemailCallBack == "true");
  {
    document.form1.name.value = sessionStorage.getItem("CONTACTNAME");
    document.form1.phone.value = sessionStorage.getItem("CONTACTNUMBER");
    document.form1.issueDescription.value = sessionStorage.getItem("VOICEMAILSUBJECT");
    document.form1.errorMessage.value = sessionStorage.getItem("ERRORMESSAGE");
    
  }

  //sessionStorage.clear();
  

})
</script>
```

All other items load properly from session storage when the page is loaded. I confirmed that the information is in session storage via the application section in the inspection section of Chrome browser and by adding alert("ISSUEDESCRIPTION"); below the problem item line and it works as expected.

I have tried the following:

- // Store your value from one page sessionStorage.setItem("values",
  "input_text");

  // Retrieve the value from another page var value =
  sessionStorage.getItem("values");
- //replacing the line with and assigning and id to the div element in the html document.getElementById("issueDescription").value = sessionStorage.getItem("ISSUEDESCRIPTION");

This is the problem element:

```
<div class="w3-row w3-section">
  <div class="w3-col" style="width:50px"><i class="w3-xxlarge  w3-animate-zoom"></i></div>
    <div class="w3-rest">
       <p>Issue Description</p>
      <input class="w3-input w3-border"  name="issueDescription" type="text" placeholder="[Issue Description Here]">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is an element on the same page that is correctly being filled with session storage information:

```
    <div class="w3-row w3-section">
      <div class="w3-col" style="width:50px"><i class="w3-xxlarge  w3-animate-zoom"></i></div>
        <div class="w3-rest">
           <p>Phone Number Used</p>
          <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="(xxx)xxx-xxxx">
        </div>
</div>
```

please tell me if I'm just referencing something incorrectly like a typo although I've spent multiple hours doublechecking everything. Wish there were a troubleshooting/debugging feature in Visual Studio Code for this kind of stuff to step through it. If there is and I'm unaware please let me know.

Comment: How can `CALLINBOUNDCALLDROPPED`, `CALLOUTBOUNDCALLDROPPED`, `ADDITIONALISSUE` and `VOICEMAILRECEIVED` be set? Did you check the condition `== "true"` ?

Comment: They are all set based on what form was used to load this page. So if it is clicked from Call Inbound template then a session storage item named respectively is set to true. and each of these have evaluated to true correctly.

Comment: <input class="red" type="button" value="Call Dropped" onclick="DSICallDropped(true);">
this is on the CallInbound page so the true is saying its an call inbound
same thing is on Calloutbound page but instead of true is set to false and evaluates correctly

Comment: I added a picture of what I see in the browser when using the page to make it easier to understand what is going on. The only issue again is the "Issue Description". all other boxes work correctly. Session Storage data is also visible in the picture as well.

Sorry didnt know how to add the description to an image which is why it says the default on the link. First post on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure of why this didn't work the first few times I tried it, but this time when I copied and pasted the elements name in the "documents.form1.issueDescription.value = sessionStorage.getItem("ISSUEDESCRIPTION");"
the issue was resolved, swear I did this on repeat late last night, must've been a spelling error.